# How to auto log off when user is inactive?

Tags: javascript, php, timer, logout

in this index page of index-customer.php

i put this javascript at the end of the head tag of index-customer.php but it does not seem to work. is it because i did not call the function of the javascript. please help me ! thank you !

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
var timer = 0;
function set_interval() {

timer = setInterval("auto_logout()", 2);
}

function reset_interval() {
if (timer != 0) {
clearInterval(timer);
timer = 0;
timer = setInterval("auto_logout()", 2);

}
}

function auto_logout() {

window.location = "Logout.php";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you use interval to 2, it's too short. Second argument to setInterval is time in milliseconds.

Comment: because i want to see whether it work in the shortest time

Comment: "is it because i did not call the function of the javascript" -> Judging by what you've posted, yes.

Comment: you are going to make the client browser overloaded with this function being called every 2 milliseconds

Comment: you didn't execute your function set_interval() to put it on work that is why you are not seeing it working

Comment: how do i execute the function ?

Comment: how do i try something to test the java script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument of setInterval should be name of the function, not the function call itself. Use timer = setInterval(auto_logout, 2000) instead
And no Quotes around function name.

Comment: 2 milliseconds is too short. Try higher values like 2000.

Comment: Did you ever call set_interval() in your code? It's inside function you need to call that to set interval  first.

Comment: i never call. how do i call ?

Comment: Call set_interval() before </script>

Comment: how do i call the function ?